# Rails association with custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am lost in all the associations options Rails offers.

I have a table for `Users`. Those `Users` have `Products`. This is simply a `has_many :products` relationship.

However, I want to provide the users with a list of products. They will choose a number of products and will add a price to it.

So basically, I have

```
USER 1 ----->  PRODUCT 1 ------> PRICE 1    <----.
       ----->  PRODUCT 2 ------> PRICE 2         |
USER 2 ----->  PRODUCT 1 ------> PRICE 3    <----¨
       ----->  PRODUCT 3 ------> PRICE 4
```

Should I create three table : `User`, `Product` and `Price`?

And what if the user wants to customize his/her product more with a quantity, need, etc.? Then should I create the following tables instead :`User`, `Product` and `ProductDetail`

This way, a `user` `has_many :product` and a `product` `has_many :product_detail`.

What is the Rails way of doing this?

I am lost with all the `has_many`, `has_one`, `has_many :through`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the following:

```
class User
  has_many :purchases
end

class Product
  has_many :purchases
end

class Purchase
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  # mongoid syntax, if using ActiveRecord, use a migration
  field :quantity, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :price, type: Float, default: 0.0
end

user = User.new
apple = Product.new
tea = Product.new
chocolate = Product.new

user.purchases.build(product: apple, price: 2.99, quantity: 1)
user.purchases.build(product: tea, price: 5.99, quantity: 2)
user.purchases.build(product: chocolate, price: 3.99, quantity: 3)
```

FYI: This kind of relations between `User`, `Product` and `Purchase` is similar to a `has_and_belongs_to_many`. When using the `has_and_belongs_to_many`, rails simply link the classes like above. Here we are doing it ourself in order to customize the `Purchase` class with `quantity` and `price`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It seems fairly simple to implement.

Comment: Glad it helped you, please consider accepting the answer. Have fun with Rails.